# Regarding Notify()

Tags: java

I was going through threads and I read that the `notify()` method is used to send a signal to one and only one of the threads that are waiting in that same object's waiting pool. The method `notifyAll()` works in the same way as `notify()`, only it sends the signal to all of the threads waiting on the `Object`.

Now my query is that if let's say I have 5 threads and one main thread, so initially the main thread starts and then five other threads start. Now I want to send notification to third thread only. How could it be possible with the use of `notify()`, since here I am sending notification to third thread only? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a specific thread to be notified, let it `wait()` on a different object, and call `notify()` on this object.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, could you please show a small program that will make understandings more clear..thanks in advance..!1

Comment: @ user1334074 :  Please accept one answer, and do your bit of work.

Comment: @user1334074 The answer seems perfectly clear to me. Any competent Java programmer should be able to turn that into code.

Comment: Hi I am a new bie, Request Youu to please if you can show through a program that will be a great help..!!

Comment: @user1334074 - sorry, but I can't provide it now, maybe in a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

The [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) class gives you more fined grained control than the `synchronized` keyword by allowing multiple wait sets per object.

You can get multiple [Conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) from a [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) using `ReentrantLock.newCondition()`. A thread may then call `Condition.await()` (similar in function to `Object.wait()`) and will block until another thread calls `Condition.signal()` (similar in function to `Object.notify()`).

The difference is you can create multiple `Conditions` for a single `ReentrantLock`. So you could create one `Condition` for each `Thread` and call `signal()` on the condition corresponding to the `Thread` which you wanted to wake up.

---

Here's a simple example code which demonstrates the above. It creates 5 `Threads` which all wait on different `Conditions` of the same `ReentrantLock`. The main thread then calls `signal()` to wake up a specific one of the `Threads`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ReentranLockTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock( );

        int numThreads = 5;

        Condition[] conditions = new Condition[numThreads];

        // start five threads, storing their associated Conditions
        for ( int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++ )
        {
            final int threadNumber = i;

            System.out.printf( "Started thread number %d%n", threadNumber );

            // to create a Condition we must lock the associated ReentrantLock
            lock.lock( );
            try
            {
                final Condition condition = lock.newCondition( );
                conditions[i] = condition;

                // start the worker Thread
                ( new Thread( )
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run( )
                    {
                        // wait on the Condition
                        // to do so we must be holding the
                        // associated ReentrantLock
                        lock.lock( );
                        try
                        {
                            condition.await( );
                        }
                        catch ( InterruptedException e )
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace( );
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            lock.unlock( );
                        }

                        // print something when signal()
                        // is called on our Condition
                        System.out.printf( "Thread number %d woke up!%n", threadNumber );
                    }
                } ).start( );
            }
            finally
            {
                lock.unlock( );
            }
        }

        // acquire the ReentrantLock and call
        // Condition.signal() to wake up Thread number 3    
        lock.lock( );
        try
        {
            System.out.printf( "Waking up Thead number %d%n", 3 );

            conditions[3].signal( );
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock( );
        }
    }
}
```

This should print the following:

> Started thread number 0
>
> Started thread number 1
>
> Started thread number 2
>
> Started thread number 3
>
> Started thread number 4
>
> Waking up Thead number 3
>
> Thread number 3 woke up!

Comment: could you also please advise an tutorial or an url where the concepts of lock and reeneterant locks are explained properly..!!

Comment: @user1334074 Oracle has a great series of official Java tutorials. Here's the beginning of the one on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). There's lots of good information there, including a page on [Lock Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html).